# Parsing file name out of ListDirectoryDetails with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, ftp, request, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to parse FTP `ListDirectoryDetails` response which comes from FileZilla FTP server.

The main problem is that FileZilla server is giving different output in different languages (cultures).

I have two following output from FileZilla server and both must be parsed which I couldn't achieve.

Format is shown below:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 Sep 02 17:07 Can
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 Jun 27 2016 Fan
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 Sep 21 12:29 AA AA
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp             44 Sep 02 17:07 Debug.txt
```

I tried to use regex to solve this issue, but it fails when compile.

My regex is:

```
(?<permissions>[drwx\-]+( (?<userandgroup>[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+) (?<size>\d+) (?<date>[A-Za-z]+ [\d:]+) (?<name> .*)
```

I need more robust regex. Maybe only filename matching regex should be better.

How can I match only filename with regex?

Comment: I think the second `(` should be `)`. See https://regex101.com/r/jK5dL8/1 (not `(?<permissions>[drwx\-]+(`, but `(?<permissions>[drwx\-]+)`)

Comment: I fixed the regex as you mentioned but it does not split response to groups. unfortunately. However compile error solved

Comment: If you provide data to test as text I - or more SO users - will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse out just a filename, just get the 9th token:

```
^(?:[^ ]+ +){8}(.*)$
```

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^(?:[^ ]+ +){8}(.*)$");
Match match = regex.Match(line);
string filename = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

---

Though for such a simple parsing, you can actually split the line to tokens by space. You do not need a regular expression.

```
string[] tokens = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string filename = tokens[8];
```

---

But if you need just a file name, do not use the `ListDirectoryDetails` in the first place. Use the `ListDirectory`. It returns file name only.

---

And if you need parsing file attributes, use an FTP client that supports the FTP `MLSD` command. The `FtpWebRequest` does not support this.

Answer (score 1):

The Regular expression in the question is: regex is:

```
(?<permissions>[drwx\-]+( (?<userandgroup>[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+) (?<size>\d+) (?<date>[A-Za-z]+ [\d:]+) (?<name> .*)
```

There are several issues with this expression.

- The 2nd '(' should be a ')'.
- The link count is missed. Add `(\d+)` (plus one space) between the first two capture groups.
- Only allows a single space is allowed between the `userandgroup` and the `size` captures. Add a `+` before `(?<size>\d+)`.
- The day of month is not matched. replace the single space in the `date` capture with  `[\d]+` (it must have one space on either side).
- The `name` capture is preceded by a space and has a space as its first character/. Delete one of them.

Merging these improvements gives the expression:

```
(?<permissions>[drwx\-]+) (\d+) (?<userandgroup>[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+) +(?<size>\d+) (?<date>[A-Za-z]+ [\d]+ [\d:]+) (?<name>.*)
```